# For loop error on the last value

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a really silly question but I cannot make a solution. My problem is, when my code come to last value I am getting an error.

```
Error: 41800 (last value of loop)
```

My code:

```
for x in (motorwayframe.index):
    if((motorwayframe['machine_id'][x]) != (motorwayframe['machine_id'][x+1])):
        motorwayframe['distance'] = np.nan
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Well, if x is the last index, obviously x+1 is going to give an index error, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

That is because if it is the last value, there is never `motorwayframe['machine_id'][x+1])`.

You can import that part manually.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a position that seems to not exists. So, you may decrement 1 in the index range in order to fix it. My advice is: use the **"range(...)"** function, instead of "foreach".